# How to get an event on file save

Tags: visual-studio-2005, macros

I am planning to integrate [NArrange](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/codegen/narrange.aspx) in my visual studio solution,i want to run this exe whenever a file is saved,Is there a way to receive event when file gets saved?
I have heard about macro but do not have much information on that.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know that you can get at a post save event for a file, but you might be able to add a post build event to the project(s) you care about. Just right click the project, in the solution, click properties, and then post build event. Whatever you add in here will run after a successful build of your project. You can get more information about pre and post build events [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: That was the very first thing which i had considered,but its not good ,Because if on a file few breakpoints are added they get shifted which makes debugging an annoying process.So ruled out

Comment: It seems like you would need to run this in a post build event. I would think if you just saved a file that wouldn't compile (because of some compile errors) NArrange would not be able to re-arrange the code.

Comment: as already mentioned these things are tried and have not been suitable for my requirement.
I specifically need it to be done on save.